# How to get rid of ghost device on FaceTime?

Tags: icloud, keychain, facetime

On my iPhone in **Settings** > **Phone** > **Calls on Other Devices**, my MacBook appears twice.
How do I get rid of the second entry?

I've tried logging out and back into iCloud, but it doesn't do the trick. I suspect it has to do with some "lost" key in iCloud Keychain.
It only appears twice there, so I'm assuming FaceTime, and ***not*** in the iCloud list of devices as well.

Any idea how can I remove that extra entry?

Comment: I once had this issue long ago, but I can’t recall what I did exactly to fix.  But, start with looking at your devices in iCloud; you might have more than one entry for your MacBook.

Comment: @Allan right, in iCloud, only one devices show. However, I suspect in keychain there must be two entries.

Comment: Keychain has nothing to do with [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) or more specifically, Handoff.

Comment: Out of curiosity, were these two devices connected to a *different*  WiFi with either device having network privacy enabled?

Comment: Possibly, it's the same MacBook, just shows up twice, I think I re-installed macOS without first signing out of iCloud or something.

Comment: You might try forgetting some common networks on both devices then rebooting.  Apple uses MAC addresses as unique identifies and privacy randomizes that address.  It conceivable that it’s remembering both addresses incorrectly.  If you forget the network, it will remove the randomized address. Just remember to save any passwords before forgetting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Apple account password, and when asked, log out of all devices, this will force a log out of whatever "ghost devices" show up in "Calls on Other Devices" list.